# Page executes very slow while curl runs

Tags: php, curl

here i explain details about my question
first check below code

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example123.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    $result = @curl_exec($ch);
```

now my question is that if "http://example123.com" is not valid or there is no such URL, then what is the problem.

i have a page there written the above. while execute the code the page takes too much time. but if i comment above 5 line then my page executes faster.

can anybody told me what is the reason behind and why the page execute very slow.

Thanks Sanjib

Answer (score 0):

Your script waits for a response (which may take 60 seconds for default_socket_timeout.)

You should set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` to make the script redirect from  http://example123.com/ to http://ww38.example123.com/, the way it does in browser.

Answer (score 0):

When `cUrl` request encounters `INVALID URI` it waits until Default connection timeout is reached, this makes page load slower.

Default Connection timeout set in `lib/connect.h` (if Linux Server)

You can change it here

```
#define DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT 300000 /* milliseconds == five minutes */
```

Or you can **Explicitly** set this in you Codes

```
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT, 100 ); # Or curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS ,0); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); # timeout in seconds
```

**`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`** : The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.

**`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`** : The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

*** (If you are using PHP as a fastCGI application then make sure you check the fastCGI timeout settings.)*